# Computer throwing an error after installing updates

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, updates

```
   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What does the error code mean and how can I fix it?

I ran these commands down below.

```
  apt-get update
  apt-get dist-upgrade
```

[image]

**Update**

The output of `df -h`

```
Filesystem  Size  Used  Avail  Use%  Mounted on
/dev/loop0  18G   17G   0      100%  /
udev        739M  4.0K  739M   1%    /dev
tmpfs       150M  860K  149M   1%    /run
none        5.0M  0     5.0M   0%    /run/lock
none        749M  0     749M   0%    /run/shm
/dev/sda1   80G   46G   35G    57%   /host
overflow    1.0M  1.0M  0      100%  /tmp
/dev/sr0    177M  177M  0      100%  /media/F.E.A.R
```

I tried uninstalling older kernels that are taking up room and still have no space left on device.

```
    apt-get remove  linux-image-3.2.0-99-generic-pae
    apt-get remove  linux-image-3.2.0-97-generic-pae
```

Comment: it might help to say precisely what commands you ran, and what sort of update it was.

Comment: Trevis, please  [edit] your post adding the output of `df -h`. (It is enough the text output as _code_). There is no space left on some partition. You can try to do `apt-get clean;  apt-get  autoremove`, `rm -rf /tmp`;  move some not essential file on the backup unit (if you have one)... and you can try to fix the system.  What is the state of your system now?

Answer (score 1):

There was no space left on your `/tmp/`. The output of `df -h` shows that even an overflow filesystem kicked in. I have found that:

> If your “/tmp” mount on a linux filesystem is mounted as overflow (often sized at 1MB), this is likely due to you not specifying “/tmp” as its own partition and your root filesystem filled up and “/tmp” was remounted as a fallback. To fix this **after you’ve cleared space**, just unmount the fallback and it should remount at its original point:

`sudo umount overflow`

It looks like there is not enough space on a device mounted at `/`.

I think Hastur's advice is good:

> try `apt-get clean; apt-get autoremove` ; `rm -rf /tmp` ; move some not essential file on the backup unit (if you have one).

You may also check and `rm` some old logs in `/var/log`.

Your `/home` probably is on the same device (unless it is symlinked to `/host/something`). Maybe there are files there you can discard.

Hastur covered the "how to fix" topic before I got to it. I cannot do better.

Comment: I tried that and it still throws me the same error

Comment: What exactly did you try? I was yet planning to expand my stub answer with suggestion(s) what to do. I don't know what you refer to. What is the output of `df -h` before `apt-get dist-upgrade`? What is it during upgrading? Run `watch df -h` in another terminal and see if you run out of space during upgrading.

Comment: i used this cd /tmp/
sudo rm -r *      then i used apt-get  dist-upgrade

Comment: That doesn't make us sure there is enough space. Watching `df -h` may do.

Comment: There is __no more space left__ on _some_ device, when some scripts  run from `/tmp`. Usually it should be referred to the same partition (the same of `/tmp`) but it is not mandatory (it can be even finished the space  on the partition where the script is installing the program...).  `df -h` will help to guess.

Comment: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       18G   17G     0 100% /
udev            739M  4.0K  739M   1% /dev
tmpfs           150M  860K  149M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            749M     0  749M   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1        80G   46G   35G  57% /host
overflow        1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /tmp
/dev/sr0        177M  177M     0 100% /media/F.E.A.R.

Comment: @Travis Wells It will be a way better to place that `df -h` output into your question (edit the question). Nevertheless thank you, it helps me help you.

Comment: sudo umount overflow
umount: /tmp: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))

Comment: You mentioned `cd /tmp/` earlier. Maybe it is still your working directory in one of your terminals, therefore it is busy. Next thing: put those crucial data in your question, not in comment (e.g "Edit: on Kamil's request I did `foo bar` and the output is...").

Answer (score 1):

**What does it means**

You can see the `apt-get` command as a more fancy and friendly version of `dpkg` that is *"a tool to install, build, remove and manage Debian packages"*.

The package are installed through `dpkg`, that calls all the scripts needed by the packgage. Those scripts may act in different ways and can have returned different exit status.

The error you receive said

> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

so at least one of the *sub-process* of `dpkg` exited with an error (the error code `(1)`). The meaning depends from the single script inside the package that fails.

You can understand more from the the lines where it is said

> cp .... no space left on device.

There is written (you have more than one) that the script fail when copy (`cp`) a file to `/sbin/` , `/lib/ ... usually on the main partition.

**How to fix**

Get an idea from `df -h` then

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
rm -rf /tmp/*         # even a reboot should empty the /tmp directory 
# mv or rm some big file elsewere.
```

Note your system can be already unstable. **It is better to avoid any reboot, until you fix.**

Supposed that you freed enough space, now you can try again

```
sudo apt-get update        # to update the file list
sudo apt-get -f install    # to fix errors

                           # in case of few space (eventually) 
sudo apt-get upgrade       # to upgrade some parts of the system
sudo apt-get clean         
sudo apt-get autoclean         
sudo apt-get autoremove
                           # Finally
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

if needed `dpkg-reconfigure -a` if `apt-get -f install` it is not enough.

Comment: Check `df -h` output (in comment under my answer). Should OP do `umount overflow` at some point? or it doesn't matter?

Comment: It depends. The `overflow` partition was mounted because it was finished the space. It is on a ramdisk. If should be remounted properly, but it should be tricky. Maybe the system is able to expand it. It will disappear as the system will reboot (if there will be space).  The OP can take some hints from [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/60731/66388). In the meantime I clean and updated the question with `df -h`: in the comment was hard to read.